# jQuery UI icon bleeds through tablesorter CSS Sticky Header

Tags: jquery-ui, tablesorter

I have a simple web application that uses jQuery (v1.12.4), jQuery UI (v1.12.1) and the tablesorter plugin (v2.30.5).  I am also using the tablesorter CSS Sticky Header Widget, and that is where I am having trouble.

On one page of the application I display an HTML table where one of the columns contains a jQuery UI icon that is a link to another page.  I use the tablesorter CSS Sticky Header Widget to keep the table header row visible as the page is scrolled.

My problem is that as you scroll down the page and table rows start moving off the top of the browser window the jQuery UI icon in each row bleeds through the sticky header row and looks terrible.

Note that I do not see the problem if I replace the jQuery UI icon with an image from a .png file.

When using the jQuery UI icon and Firefox as my browser, I can get the desired behavior of having the icon disappear behind the sticky header by adding a CSS `z-index: 1` to the `<thead>` element of the table.  When using Internet Explorer as my browser, I can get the desired behavior by putting the CSS `z-index: 1` on the `<td>` element for the problematic column header.  However, I have not found any solution when using Chrome, which happens to be the preferred browser of my target audience.

Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/jquery-ui-themes-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jQuery/tablesorter-master/css/theme.blue.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="table1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Column1</td>
                    <td>Column2</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>r1c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r2c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r3c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r4c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r5c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r6c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r7c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r8c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r9c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>r10c1</td>
                    <td><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/tablesorter-master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
        <script src="jQuery/tablesorter-master/js/widgets/widget-cssStickyHeaders.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#table1").tablesorter({
                    theme: "blue",

                    widgets: ["cssStickyHeaders"]
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" solution would be to give the icons a negative z-index, then remove all the background colors from the table. The problem with this method is that if you want to add zebra striping, you'll have to use a more complicated method to achieve it (check out the css in the [css highlighting demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-css-highlighting.html)).

See if this method works for you ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bbxxomhx/1248/)):

```
.tablesorter-blue, .tablesorter-blue td {
  background: transparent;
}
.ui-icon {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Mottie, your "easiest" solution does work for my simple test program above.  However, my real web application uses the zebra widget and I was not able to quickly figure out how to get striping to work with your solution.  I did find two easy alternative solutions, though:  1) Use Font Awesome icons instead of jQuery UI icons, or 2) Use the tablesorter Sticky Header Widget instead of the CSS Sticky Header Widget.